# jQuery draggable not working after dragging and append to new container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't figure why jquery draggable stops to work after dragging the objects from one place to the other. The objective was to add values from left to right after the object is dragged within the threshold, it works for the first time but stops working after the elements is appended onto the new container.

Do I miss something?

```
$( ".draggable-right" ).draggable({
    containment: "#div-item-court"
    ,scroll: false
    ,stop:function(event, ui) {
        var wrapper = $(this).parent().offset(); //$("div.box-left").offset();
        var wrapperDestination = $("div.box-left").offset();
        var borderLeft = parseInt($(this).parent().css("border-left-width"),10); //parseInt($("#div.box-left").css("border-left-width"),10);
        var borderTop = parseInt($(this).parent().css("border-top-width"),10); //parseInt($("#div.box-left").css("border-top-width"),10);
        var pos = ui.helper.offset();
        var x = $("#source_x").val(pos.left - wrapper.left - borderLeft);
        var y = $("#source_y").val(pos.top - wrapper.top - borderTop);
        console.log(wrapper.left +" - "+ pos.left +" - "+ borderLeft +" - "+ wrapperDestination.left);

        if (parseInt(pos.left)/parseInt(wrapper.left) <= 0.85){ //positioned to the left, changing family
            curLeftTotal = $("#div-total-left").text();
            curRightTotal = $("#div-total-right").text();
            toAdd = $(this).text();
            curLeftTotal = parseInt(curLeftTotal) + parseInt(toAdd); //add to the left family
            curRightTotal = parseInt(curRightTotal) - parseInt(toAdd);
            $("#div-total-left").html(curLeftTotal);
            $("#div-total-right").html(curRightTotal);

            //remove the object from its parent and add to the new parent
            $(this).removeClass("draggable-right").addClass("draggable-left").removeAttr("style").css({'background-color' : 'red', 'position' : 'relative'});
            temp = $(this).clone();
            $(this).remove();

            //create to the new parent
            $("div.box-left").append(temp);

            //make the element draggable
            temp.draggable(); <<< to make the newly added element draggable again

            //console.log(toAdd +"-"+ curLeftTotal +"-"+ curRightTotal);
        }   
    }
});
```

Please see the code at https://jsfiddle.net/mirageservo/adr47hn5/

Thanks,

PS. Somewhat the code is not working in jsFiddle

EDIT: jsFiddle is working now, likewise, I was able to add the behavior to the newly added element. however, its odd because the draggable is now empty.

```
....
temp.draggable()
```

The question now is how to recurse and make the draggable same as the behavior above, I don't think the following code below is correct:

```
temp.draggable({
  ... same code above here ...
});
```

Need your inputs and suggestions.

Thanks,

Comment: Can't reproduce here. Just added jQuery 1.12.3 and jQuery UI 1.11 and everything seems ok!

Comment: @FelippeDuarte, does this worked in your trial?  $(this).removeClass("draggable-right").addClass("draggable-left").removeAttr("style").css({'background-color' : 'red', 'position' : 'relative'});
            temp = $(this).clone();
            $(this).remove();

            //create to the new parent
            $("div.box-left").append(temp);

Comment: @FelippeDuarte, when you moved the box from one container to another, where you able to move it back and forth?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make a variable object "temp" draggable.
Do it like this:

```
        temp = $(this).clone().addClass('tempClass'); //add tempClass

        $(this).remove();

        //create to the new parent
        $("div.box-left").append(temp);

        //make the element draggable
        $(".tempClass").draggable(); <<< to make the newly added ".tempClass" element draggable
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made some changes to your code, the way things should be. I think you should do the calculations in a different way, using the div position + width. Of course, you could and should refactor this code to make it better, to avoid duplication and stuff.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      //console.log("jQuery Works");
      var totleft = 0;
      var totright = 0;

      $("div.box-left > div > p").each(function(i){
         totleft = parseInt(totleft) + parseInt($(this).text());
      });
      $("#div-total-left").html(totleft);

      $("div.box-right > div > p").each(function(i){
         totright = parseInt(totright) + parseInt($(this).text());
      });
      $("#div-total-right").html(totright);
  });

  var draggableLeft = {
        containment: "#div-item-court"
        ,scroll: false
        ,stop:function(event, ui) {
            var wrapper = $(this).parent().offset(); //$("div.box-left").offset();
            var wrapperDestination = $("div.box-right").offset();
            var borderLeft = parseInt($(this).parent().css("border-left-width"),10); //parseInt($("#div.box-left").css("border-left-width"),10);
            var borderTop = parseInt($(this).parent().css("border-top-width"),10); //parseInt($("#div.box-left").css("border-top-width"),10);
            var pos = ui.helper.offset();
            var x = $("#source_x").val(pos.left - wrapper.left - borderLeft);
            var y = $("#source_y").val(pos.top - wrapper.top - borderTop);

            /*
            check the position of the object
            if the object is now in the new family 
            the value should add to the new family 
            and minus from the old family
            */
            var boxLeftPos = $('.box-left').position().left + $('.box-left').width();

            if (parseInt(pos.left)+$(this).width() > boxLeftPos){ //positioned to the right, changing family
                curLeftTotal = $("#div-total-left").text();
                curRightTotal = $("#div-total-right").text();
                toAdd = $(this).text();
                curLeftTotal = parseInt(curLeftTotal) - parseInt(toAdd); //remove from the left family
                curRightTotal = parseInt(curRightTotal) + parseInt(toAdd);
                $("#div-total-left").html(curLeftTotal);
                $("#div-total-right").html(curRightTotal);

                //remove the object from its parent and add to the new parent
                $(this).removeClass("draggable-left").addClass("draggable-right").removeAttr("style").css({'background-color' : 'blue', 'position' : 'relative'});
                //create to the new parent
                $("div.box-right").append($(this).detach());
                $(this).draggable(getDraggableRight());
            }
        }
    };

  var draggableRight = {
        containment: "#div-item-court"
        ,scroll: false
        ,stop:function(event, ui) {
            var wrapper = $(this).parent().offset(); //$("div.box-left").offset();
            var wrapperDestination = $("div.box-left").offset();
            var borderLeft = parseInt($(this).parent().css("border-left-width"),10); //parseInt($("#div.box-left").css("border-left-width"),10);
            var borderTop = parseInt($(this).parent().css("border-top-width"),10); //parseInt($("#div.box-left").css("border-top-width"),10);
            var pos = ui.helper.offset();
            var x = $("#source_x").val(pos.left - wrapper.left - borderLeft);
            var y = $("#source_y").val(pos.top - wrapper.top - borderTop);

      var boxLeftPos = $('.box-left').position().left + $('.box-left').width();

            if (parseInt(pos.left)+$(this).width() > boxLeftPos){ //positioned to the right, changing family

                curLeftTotal = $("#div-total-left").text();
                curRightTotal = $("#div-total-right").text();
                toAdd = $(this).text();
                curLeftTotal = parseInt(curLeftTotal) + parseInt(toAdd); //add to the left family
                curRightTotal = parseInt(curRightTotal) - parseInt(toAdd);
                $("#div-total-left").html(curLeftTotal);
                $("#div-total-right").html(curRightTotal);

                //remove the object from its parent and add to the new parent
                $(this).removeClass("draggable-right").addClass("draggable-left").removeAttr("style").css({'background-color' : 'red', 'position' : 'relative'});
                //create to the new parent
                $("div.box-left").append($(this).detach());
                $(this).draggable(getDraggableLeft());
            }   
        }
 };

  function getDraggableRight() {
    return draggableRight;
  }
  function getDraggableLeft() {
    return draggableLeft;
  }

  $(function() {
        $( ".draggable-left" ).draggable(draggableLeft);
    $( ".draggable-right" ).draggable(draggableRight);
  });
```

Here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/adr47hn5/7/

Comment: Why does the parent div moves and sometimes the children when added to the new parent is outside the parent div? How can I prevent the parent div from resizing and force the content to wrap?

Comment: see this, https://jsfiddle.net/mirageservo/adr47hn5/9/ the parent div for the right column moved below, while trying to move all items from the right to left will move the left div to move also, can we have it fixed in one place?